# When a UTxO becomes available for consumption?

Tags: plutus, utxo

In the [Gift.hs](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week02/src/Week02/Gift.hs) example from the second lecture in Plutus Pioneers Program, when I give ada, a UTxO is produced. When I want to grab that ada in the same block, it fails (There is no input or output when simulated in the palyground). But when I wait for one block and then try to grab, It succeeds.

My conclusion is we cannot produce and consume a UTxO in the same block. We can only consume a UTxO from the next block onward. Am I right or...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is correct. For a UTxO to be consumed it first has to exist on the blockchain. For it to exist on the blockchain the transaction that created it must exist in a block that has been confirmed by the network.

Answer (score 3):

You can only grab the gift once it's confirmed on the ledger. Search for `awaitTxConfirmed` in the source code.

That effect may have configurable level of confirmation in the future as indicated in the [source code](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/cc953b36ec9681cc28edf1accf08f48a31238e69/plutus-contract/src/Plutus/Contract/Effects/AwaitTxConfirmed.hs).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, at least with a recent version of cardano-cli (don't know about earlier ones, but I assume it would work too) to issue two transactions sequentially where the output of tx n is used as the input of tx n + 1. Both transactions will be put into the same block.

[Here's](https://cardanoscan.io/block/5723141) a block where I've done so a few days ago, the first two transactions are by me. You can see that the second tx uses the first one as input.

Edit: In the context of plutus smart contracts however, I think Matthias is correct.

Comment: This isn't a limitation of Plutus scripts in general, but the plutus-contract library. Transaction chaining is possible with and without Plutus scripts involved.